# SQL Server: Comparing multiple tables using EXCEPT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, compare, except

I'm trying to compare some tables in a pair of databases using EXCEPT. The script should output the number of rows that are different between the two tables. The script below will retrieve the tables and columns that I want to include, but I'm wondering if there is any way to build my query without using dynamic sql?

I have no problem using dynamic sql. I'm just curious to know if there's a better way. TIA.

```
DECLARE @tbl sysname, @col sysname
DECLARE tblCursor CURSOR FOR
   SELECT TABLE_NAME
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
      ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
OPEN tblCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM tblCursor INTO @tbl
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
   DECLARE colCursor CURSOR FOR
      SELECT COLUMN_NAME
         FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
         WHERE TABLE_NAME=@tbl AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'PR'
   OPEN colCursor
   FETCH NEXT FROM colCursor INTO @col
   WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
   BEGIN
      -- Do I have to build dynamic SQL string for
      -- columns here or is there a better way?
      FETCH NEXT FROM colCursor INTO @col
   END
   CLOSE colCursor
   DEALLOCATE colCursor

   /* Use EXCEPT to compare two tables
   DECLARE @tblDeviationCount int = (
      SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM (
            SELECT [Column1], [Column3]
               FROM @tbl
               EXCEPT (
                  SELECT [Column1], [Column3]
                     FROM @tblOther
               )
            UNION
            SELECT [Column1], [Column3]
               FROM @tblOther
               EXCEPT (
                  SELECT [Column1], [Column3]
                     FROM @tbl
               )
         ) subq
   )
   */

   PRINT @tbl + ': ' + @tblDeviationCount + ' deviations found.'
   FETCH NEXT FROM tblCursor INTO @tbl
END
CLOSE tblCursor
DEALLOCATE tblCursor
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you are trying to compare here...do you have two tables and you are trying to compare their columns to discover the difference?  Or are you trying to detect differences at the row level?

Comment: Hmm...I thought it would be apparent from my comment block, but I'm trying to determine if there are any values in tbl that are not in tblOther and vice versa. I know the syntax in my comment is not valid.

Comment: Your column cursor appears to do nothing at all (of use), and at no point do you declare or set `@tblother`, so the commented SQL does not really fit in with the rest of your code. But no, there is no way you can replace object names with variables without using dynamic sql.

Comment: Do you need to dynamically grab the Columns of the table? are you trying to build a generic stored proc that will compare two tables both of which are not known at runtime? Just trying to figure out why there is a cursor getting the column names from a DMO

Comment: @garthd, You can dynamically create a query tables with Dynamic sql using variables for the column names. For example DECLARE \@SQL = 'SELECT ' + \@COLUMN1 + ' FROM ' +\@TABLE1;  had to use the backslash to get past SO comment editor

Comment: GarethD: Yeah, I wanted to make sure that I was going down the right path before I proceeded to implement the rest of the script. If what you say is true, submit an answer and I'll mark it.

gh9: Yes, this will be a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to replace object names with variables in a query without using dynamic sql, so you are heading down the right path. As an aside though you can remove your column cursor, and you can get a full column list using SQL Server's XML extensions to concatenate the columns:

```
DECLARE @Cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = STUFF((SELECT ',' + c.Name
                                    FROM sys.columns c
                                    WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tbl)
                                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');
```

This won't make much difference at all, but every little helps, and avoids allocating memory to a cursor. It does also make it easier to get the columns common to both tables as you can use an INNER JOIN, or INTERSECT to get the relevant columns.

The other change I would make (although this is much more subjective) is that I would use the system views for your schema
information, rather than the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, the information schema, although ANSI standard and more guaranteed does
have its flaws, and the system views are more accurate and contain more information. [Aaron Bertrand makes a much better case than me in this article](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views).